# How can I check for how long the instance has been running on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Scheduled a cron job to hit empty endpoints just to keep the instance running. How do I check the instance has been running for how long just to make sure it's the same instance that has been running since start.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, so in Instances menu under App Engine it shows information related to the instance which includes Start Time.

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways to check how much time the instance has been running.

The first one is through the Instances menu, as you said.

The second one would be through the [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances). In the response you can see the start time as one of the json attributes.

The third one would be through the gcloud command line [console](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/describe) with the command:

> gcloud app instances describe --service=SERVICE --version=VERSION NAME

That will return you similar information as in the API request that also includes the start time.